# Adding db_authenticatable to an already working omniauthable devise installation breaks sign_up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I have a Rails application currently working with omniauth-facebook and Devise (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), and I wanted to add the normal db authentication, which for some reasons breaks omniauth when I use sign_up_and_redirect @user.

Here is the devise declaration:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :rememberable, :trackable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [ :facebook ]
```

and here where I login my user after returning from Facebook:

```
def facebook
  @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth( request.env["omniauth.auth"] )
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
  set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook")
end
```

Here is what I see in my logs:

```
I, [2014-11-05T18:25:20.489760 #94984]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Nov/2014 18:25:20] "GET /users/auth/facebook HTTP/1.1" 302 298  0.0169
I, [2014-11-05T18:25:20.910383 #94984]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Nov/2014 18:25:21] "GET /unauthenticated?code=AQBd86XvpY3mc75U6mEO7b_BbRTLPfb5r5YrRPHcJVKbGZN7kX_86xTZPeL-keScEPsMxbgkkYOlc2ZJXX34gUn8ZBW2UG74p1QIqe-aWEgAiZlXzVtqXsMGGTQzw1Wdi-UF1BnL0U0_7CYRNHzHlku7L6WO8-bQsQXjDR1JEDbLOiFcliznZw1QyKDbmZ9XWXU76R1ss8Ms1yo7_nMRe_YPQ6rFFgiBPsKnKfGQwpIiHB_uqF_JRF3jdTIzkVEg5G4QdQMZY-HIAAmi7d0ejiR1Qo&state=6ae72bde36266fa2c4e57437e66923d1f5c5c2d760dee7e7 HTTP/1.1" 302 - 1.0151
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Nov/2014 18:25:21] "GET /users/sign_in HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0438
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Nov/2014 18:25:22] "GET /jquery.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0113
```

It appears to me that the Omniauth (successful) authentication triggers for some reasons the other authentication. I've even tried to for sign_in_and_redirect User.first but I have the same result.

Seems to me that the behaviour of sign_in_and_redirect changed after adding db_authenticatable, and I'm not able to force authentication anymore. Anybody ever experienced anything like this? TIA

Answer (score 0):

Confirmation was required so I needed to

```
      user.skip_confirmation!
```